# Project Server 2013 Upgrade error

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server, pwa

I have migrated PWA instance to new servers. When I try to run upgrade state it shows following error.

> Upgrade session failed due to unexpected exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__12(SqlDataReader reader)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.ProcessSqlReader(String monitoredScopeName, String sqlCommandText, Action`1 processRowAction)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.GetStoredProceduresFromTargetDatabase()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7.<Initialize>b__2()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object param0)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.Initialize()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.SqlMetadataManager.InitializeObjectsFromTargetDatabase()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object param0)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.SqlMetadataManager.Initialize()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.PSDatabaseSequence.RefreshSqlObjects()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.PSDatabaseSequence.PostUpgrade()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.RunUpgradeSession(Object lockObject, IUpgradable iup, SPUpgradeOperationFlags upgradeOperationFlags)  ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetStoredProceduresFromTargetDatabase>b__12(SqlDataReader reader)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.ProcessSqlReader(String monitoredScopeName, String sqlCommandText, Action`1 processRowAction)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.GetStoredProceduresFromTargetDatabase()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__2()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.Initialize()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.SqlMetadataManager.InitializeObjectsFromTargetDatabase()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__10(Object param0)  ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetStoredProceduresFromTargetDatabase>b__12(SqlDataReader reader)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.ProcessSqlReader(String monitoredScopeName, String sqlCommandText, Action`1 processRowAction)     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.GetStoredProceduresFromTargetDatabase()     at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Upgrade.TargetDatabaseObjectProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__2()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__c()     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10(Object param0)<---  <---  .  e8e3827b-77f9-4003-bbe8-c64d7a989dfe
>   06/10/2016 15:21:26.71  powershell (0x1C80) 0x1844  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPUpgradeSession    ajxl4   INFO    ======================================================================================  e8e3827b-77f9-4003-bbe8-c64d7a989dfe

No clue what is going wrong here.